# Open application on button tapped with Bundle Identifier (Without URL scheme)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-privateapi

I'm currently developing an app and I'm trying to add a button which would open another app installed on my phone when the button is tapped

I've tried looking for the URL scheme for the app but I can't find it. Only thing I can find is the bundle ID. So i thought maybe there's a way to use the bundle ID to open the app through private APIs in Swift? My phone is jailbroken if that helps. Below is my code:

```
@IBAction func openAppTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apspace/id1413678891?mt=8")! as URL)      
   
}
```

I managed to upon the app on the appstore upon tapping the button but I want a way to open the app directly without using url schemes but instead using the bundle id and/or private APIs. Any help would be really really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To open another app, you are either going to have to use some kind of extension provided by that app or figure out their URL scheme and reverse engineer it.

The first thing you could try is looking at the app's Info.plist and seeing if they have defined a URLScheme for their app. If not, and they haven't implemented an extension, then I think you're SOL.

If they did define it, try using it to open their app and see what happens, they might have some code that rejects or accepts a request to open their app based on the format of the URL after their scheme. If you can't figure it out with trial and error, you could use the fact that your phone is jailbroken to decompile their app and hunt down the URL parsing logic which is likely in their AppDelegate. From there you could try and build a URL that you can use to successfully open their app every time.

Comment: Like i mentioned in my post the app doesn't have any URL scheme thats why i'm trying to find a way to open it with the bundle ID cos apparently there's a way to do it using private APIs

Comment: Sorry, I thought that when you said "... I can't find it ..." you meant that you didn't know where to look. If there is no URL scheme then there is no way to open another app in a production environment without using a crazy hack like importing XCTest, importing private headers from XCUIApplication, and then using those to open the other app by bundle ID.

Comment: I think there's a way to do it by importing LSApplicationWorkspace header file but again this header file is in Objective C and i'm not sure how to import it in Swift. I could use something like `openApplicationWithBundleID:(id)arg1`

Answer (score 0):

This is a private api and it worked for me

```
   func openApp(bundleID: String) -> Bool {
            guard let obj = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace") as? NSObject else { return false }
            let workspace = obj.perform(Selector(("defaultWorkspace")))?.takeUnretainedValue() as? NSObject
            let open = workspace?.perform(Selector(("openApplicationWithBundleID:")), with: bundleID) != nil
            return open
 }
```